# ASP.net validator regular expression and accented names / characters

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I have a asp.net control that is using a regular expression to validate the users input for first name and last name. It works for up to 40 characters...and I think by the looks of the expression it also allows ' for names like O'Donald and maybe hypenated names too.

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$"
```

My problem is with accented names/characters e.g. Spanish and French names that may contain for example ñ are not allowed. Does anyone know how to modify my expression to take this into account?

Answer (score 7):

You want

> \p{L}: any kind of letter from any language.

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

`\p{L}` or `\pL` is every character in the unicode table that has the property "letter". So it will match every letter from the unicode table.

You can use this within your character class like this

```
ValidationExpression="^[\p{L}''-'\s]{1,40}$"
```

Working C# test:

```
String[] words = { "O'Conner", "Smith", "Müller", "fooñ", "Fooobar12" };

foreach (String s in words) {

    Match word = Regex.Match(s, @"
                                         ^                     # Match the start of the string
                                          [\p{L}''-'\s]{1,40}  
                                         $                     # Match the end of the string
                                       ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    if (word.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": valid");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": invalid");
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I haven't had time to try this yet, but I will give it a go and provide feedback. It makes sense to me though, so thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried this but it still seems to fail for example if I type first name that include the ñ character is does not work. Even worse, normal names in english are not allowed? I am confused.

Comment: I can't test it with asp.net but its working on c#, so I would say the regex should be OK.